# How for each loop is working in this rectangular array?

Tags: java, for-loop, multidimensional-array, foreach

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Recarraysumandmat 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        Scanner kb=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter row and column size: ");
        int n=kb.nextInt();
        int m=kb.nextInt();
        int sum=0;
        int [][]arr;
        arr=new int[n][m];
        for (int[] arr1 : arr) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr1.length; j++) {
                arr1[j] = kb.nextInt();
            }
        }
        for (int[] arr1 : arr) 
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr1.length; j++) {
                System.out.print(arr1[j] + " ");
                sum = sum + arr1[j];
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("The sum is: "+sum);
    }
}
```

Please tell me how the for-each loop is working here for taking the input in rectangular array and why NetBeans IDE is recommending for each loop over the normal for loop I have studied that for-each loop is only useful for traversing array not for taking input in the array.

Please explain about how for-each loop is working here with rectangular array if you could.

Comment: The first for-each loop is basically just reading the rows and then, inside the rows, it's reading in different values for the columns. The second for-each loop is basically just doing the same, but is instead printing the values in the array and summing them. The statement `for (int[] arr1 : arr)` basically means "for every row in the array, do". Where every row would also be an array of values, i.e. arr1 is an array representing that row.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I want to know how the reference where arr is pointing is changing in the first loop suppose arr is pointing to 8000 and it has 3 rows and they have different addresses and they have the columns of different address then how the for each loop is going to every row and giving us the size of the column of that row could you tell me internally how this works because it is not available on internet.

Comment: 2D-arrays in java are actually not 2D arrays, but an array of arrays, so what happens is the 1D array would contain references to other arrays(rows). When the loop is entered and an array is set for each iteration, it's just following a reference to get that array and then get its size using `arr1.length`(which is the size of that array which would be the column number of the base array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2D-arrays in java are actually not 2D arrays, but an array of arrays, so what happens is the 1D array would contain references to other arrays(rows). When the loop is entered and an array is set for each iteration, it's just following a reference to get that array and then get its size using arr1.length(which is the size of that array which would be the column number of the base array)